# Reading from a file and input it an array

Tags: java

I'm Migz and I'm a newbie in java. I'm taking up programming and had a homework where we should write and read from a file.

Its kinda like this. I managed to write the code for writing into the file and reading it. The problem is when I'm reading the file using scanner, and after that running the program, it just read the whole file as a text. It was a table of observation about birds. The file(birds.txt) looked like this.

Hawk,M,Amsterdam,may2013 ( I put these into different array. One for name,gender,place and date.

Eagle,F,France,september2013

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Skriv inn fugletypen");
String s = sc.next();
try{ 
    FileReader lesFil = new FileReader("fugler.txt");
    BufferedReader filBuff = new BufferedReader(lesFil);
    while((s = filBuff.readLine()) != null) { 
        System.out.println(s);
    } 
    lesFil.close();
} catch ( IOException e) { 
    System.out.println("Error"); 
}
```

Comment: i used both filereader and scanner and got the same result. it only reads the file.

Comment: im studying in Norway by the way, that is why some of the words in the code is in Norwegian

Comment: my code only reads the whole file. but i need to write the specific bird and output its gender,place and date. for example "Input the type of bird;" and i write Hawk. The program should only output all the Hawks inside the text file. How do i do it?

Comment: Use ``String#split``to split your lines at the comma, and ``String#equals`` or ``#equalsIgnoreCase`` to check if the name in the line matches. Btw, the ``Scanner`` has nothing to do with reading the file in your case.

Comment: can you show me how to do it?

Comment: are we allowed to use String#split in java?

Comment: Why should it not be allowed?

Comment: i meam i still dont know how to use it. had java for 2 weeks.